# How to arrange images inside Relative Layout

Tags: android, xml

I am just starting with Android and cannot find a way to arrange the images the way I want.

This is what I am looking for:

[image]

This is the code I am currently using, to arrange the images, which unfortunately does not work.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:src="@drawable/delicio"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logoerrado"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

How can I arrange the images how I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get image1 in the upper right hand corner, use

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

To get image 2 in the center horizontally, use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`.  Then add enough padding via `android:paddingTop` to get it down as far as you want.

If you want another layout beneath image2, like I see in your drawing, just put `android:layout_below="@+id/img2"` to it.

Comment: Worked like a charm, will be marked as the answer as soon as I can.